# socket.io showing polling-xhr.js:268 POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=ND_oTrA 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am facing a socket.io connection issue. I know this question is already asked many times. And I tried solutions too from those questions but none of the solution work for me.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000, () => console.log('3000 is the port'));
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('connection ')
    if (!users[socket.id]) {
        users[socket.id] = socket.id;
    }
    socket.emit("yourID", socket.id);
    io.sockets.emit("allUsers", users);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        delete users[socket.id];
    })

    socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
        io.to(data.userToCall).emit('hey', {signal: data.signalData, from: data.from});
    })

    socket.on("acceptCall", (data) => {
        io.to(data.to).emit('callAccepted', data.signal);
    })
});
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Hi @Jayna, could you share the solutions you have tried and the errors you got! It helps people to build a perspective of the problem in order to help you.

Comment: @faruk13, I already mentioned the error -> **polling-xhr.js:268 POST-http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NE01aqn 404 (Not Found)** and for a solution, I put the latest one..

Comment: @faruk13, Is it something related to port? As my front end REACT is running on port 3000. But it is not even logging the connection when socket connection established..

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on `8000` port but you logged that it is running on `3000`. Hence try connecting it using `localhost:8000` connection url.

You can also change server to run on port `3000` instead of `8000`.

```
const PORT=3000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`${PORT} is the port`));
```